# Invalid Preview Surface in Video Recorder Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-videoview, mediarecorder

I want to open a camera preview as soon as I open an activity "VideoRecordingActivity" and then start recording when the button "btnRecord" is clicked. But I am getting this error "Invalid Preview Surface". How can I solve this? My code is given below:

> VideoRecordingActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        videoPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "/myVideo.mp4";
        btnRecord = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
        imgBtnCancel = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCancel);
        imgBtnOk = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConfirm);
        videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.SampleVideoView);

        var recordOk = PrepareVideoRecorder();
        btnRecord.Click += delegate
        {
            if (!hasRecordClick)
            {
                if (recordOk)
                {
                    _mediaRecorder.Start();
                    hasRecordClick = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ReleaseMediaRecorder();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _mediaRecorder.Stop();
                ReleaseMediaRecorder();
                camera.Lock();
                btnRecord.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                imgBtnOk.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                imgBtnCancel.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        };
        }

    bool PrepareVideoRecorder()
    {
        camera = Camera.Open();
        _mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        camera.Unlock();
        _mediaRecorder.SetCamera(camera);
        _mediaRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Camera);
        _mediaRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Camcorder);

        _mediaRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.Default);
        _mediaRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.Default);
        _mediaRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.Default);

        _mediaRecorder.SetOutputFile(GetOutputMediaFilePath());
        _mediaRecorder.SetPreviewDisplay(videoView.Holder.Surface);
        try
        {
            _mediaRecorder.Prepare();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("caught exception {0}", ex);
            ReleaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show us the stack trace?